# Xcode make imprinted UITextField that expands automatically

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

I want to let a user add a title to a book cover. I want the textfield (not the text) look embossed which would be quite simple using a appropriate image behind the textfield. BUT I want to textfield to expand when the user types more than one line.

Can you add an embossed effect (that is inner shadow to one half and outer glow to the other have) to a ui textfield programmatically?

Do you need to use an image that resizes? How would that work?

Comment: use textview instead of textField

Answer (score 0):

`UItextField` is specifically one-line only. Use `UItextView` for multiline, and you can change its height depending on text...